# Timestamp doesn't appear when a formula is applied in column A

Tags: timestamp

I am using below VBA code for Timestamp Input time and updated time. When I am typing manually in column A cell but when I applying a formula timestamp doesnt work lets Say I have a formula =If(K2>L2,"BUY","") After applying this formula in cloumn A condition is met but timestamp doesn't work.
VBA code if:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Timestamp Data
'   TeachExcel.com

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

'Your data table range
Set myTableRange = Range("A2:A50")

'Check if the changed cell is in the data tabe or not.
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Stop events from running
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Column for the date/time
Set myDateTimeRange = Range("E" & Target.Row)
'Column for last updated date/time
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("F" & Target.Row)

'Determine if the input date/time should change
If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    myDateTimeRange.Value = Now

End If

'Update the updated date/time value
myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

'Turn events back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please check

Comment: Please format properly your post. The title should be short and the question text more detailed.

Comment: Hi Michael I have made changes please check

Comment: What is your programming language?